# Apache Camel Infinite Loop on error

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm having a problem with an infinite loop in Apache Camel (2.15.2). The route shown below works fine under normal conditions. However, in some rare cases, an infinite loop is created which consumes all CPU. I'm not sure what causes this, but I have a feeling it's related to when the remote application producing messages on the route is shutting down.

Code to configure the route (using RouteBuilder):

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    errorHandler(deadLetterChannel(
        "file:messages/myRoute?fileName=${date:now:yyyyMMdd-HHmm-ssSSS}.xml")
        .useOriginalMessage()
        .maximumRedeliveries(10)
        .delayPattern("1:5000");
    onException(java.net.ConnectException.class).handled(true);

    fromF("myEndpoint")
        .routeId("myRoute")
        .bean(messageHandler, "process");
}
```

The bean handling the message:

```
public void process(final String message) {
    final MyMessage message = (MyMessage) marshaller.getXStream().fromXML(message);
    ...some processing...
    producer.sendBody("anotherEndpoint", marshaller.getXStream().toXML(message));
}
```

I've made several thread dumps and they all show stuff similar to this:

```
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.DefaultConverterLookup.lookupConverterForType(DefaultConverterLookup.java:56)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:56)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1206)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1190)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1061)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1052)
at com.example.message.MessageHandler.process(MessageHandler.java:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:408)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:279)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:252)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:171)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:87)
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:103)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:746)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:684)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:651)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:315)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:253)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1164)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1156)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1053)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Perhaps my errorHandler and/or onException are incorrect? Thank you!

Comment: What kind of endpoint is **anotherEndpoint**? Why do you manually unmarshal, marshal, send within your `process` method instead of using regular Camel?

Comment: What endpoint is "MyEndpoint"?

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti Both endpoints are ActiveMQ.

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna I've inherited this code so I'm afraid I'm not sure why it's done this way. anotherEndpoint is an ActiveMQ endpoint

Comment: You are sure that the issue is not that an error is occurs, the message is reverted back to the queue and is then picked up again, and the whole process repeats itself? Normally, after a few attempts the message should be sent to a backout queue for later investigation.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti Thank you for your response. In case of an error, wouldn't there be 10 redeliveries following the 1:5000 pattern? Also, which I forgot to mention in the question, when the issue is triggered, it happens on multiple routes at the same time.

Comment: I am not sure about the redelivery settings, you can setting them when you configure your activemq connection. But I would think best thing is to do is move the message to a backout queue when an error occurs. Have you included debug logging to see what is going on at a deeper level?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by backout queue? I'll try to enable debug logging and wait for it to happen again. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infinite loop may be related to a concurrency issue in the underlying x-stream library. See https://github.com/x-stream/xstream/issues/2 and the related issues.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I can confirm that this was actually caused by a concurrency/initialization issue in the x-stream library. I should have update this question myself.